# Form Conversion from doPost to doGet

Tags: forms, servlets

I have developed one application and facing issue with security stuff. 
My application is running in doPost method which doesn't explicit the URL in browser. If I'm trying to change the doPost to doGet (using webdeveloper tools-->Forms), my application's URL will be displaying explicitly. So I need to throw an error/stop app response, If user tries to change the forms from doPost to doGet ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the question here is: Why do you regard it as a security issue, that the URL might be displayed in the browser?

- In case you don't want the user to have access to the URL or other request data, you probably have fundamental design problem, as the user can track the post request using the developer tools.
- In case you don't want somebody else than the user to see the URL and thus think it should not be displayed in the browser, I would not worry, as the user has to actively and consciously "mess" with your application to achieve this behavior.

In general it is probably a good idea to throw errors and prevent the request from being processed if your front end does not behave as expected.